# How to print each level-one json field in its own line in jq?

Tags: jq

When I pretty print a json file using

```
cat xx.json | jq .
```

, it prints every field in its own line. This causes extremely long output if, e.g., the json file contains arrays of x y coordinates.

*Is there a way to use `jq` to print each level-one field (i.e. direct child of the root) of the json object in its own line?*

More generally, is there a way to expand the json object up to level `k`, so that each level k child is printed in one line that contains its descendants (with levels greater than k).

-- Clarification:

A small illustrative example is:

```
echo '{"type":"MultiPolygon","coordinates":[[[[-94.9065,38.9884],[-94.8682,39.0596],[-94.6053,39.0432],[-94.6108,38.8460],[-94.6108,38.7365],[-94.9668,38.7365],[-95.0544,38.7365],[-95.0544,38.9829]]]]}"' | jq .
```

generates:

```
{
  "type": "MultiPolygon",
  "coordinates": [
    [
      [
        [
          -94.9065,
          38.9884
        ],
        [
          -94.8682,
          39.0596
        ],
        [
          -94.6053,
          39.0432
        ],
        [
          -94.6108,
          38.846
        ],
        [
          -94.6108,
          38.7365
        ],
        [
          -94.9668,
          38.7365
        ],
        [
          -95.0544,
          38.7365
        ],
        [
          -95.0544,
          38.9829
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ]
}
```

I'd like to print all of the value of `"coordinates"` and the value of each of its sibling in one line (and more generally, I'd like to achieve the same if the `coordinates` field is at level k of the root, instead of level 1).

Comment: Could you share an example in- and output to illustrate what you mean?

Comment: @pLumo sure, please see the edits.

Comment: Is this just for visualization purposes? Wouldn't it be better to pipe your output to your favorite editor and take advantage of folds (e.g. in vim, foldmethod=indent and foldlevel)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `jq` utility does not provide this level of control over its pretty-printing.  The easiest hack that you could probably do with `jq` is to output parts of the structure serialized:

```bash
$ jq '.coordinates[][] |= map(@json)' file
{
  "type": "MultiPolygon",
  "coordinates": [
    [
      [
        "[-94.9065,38.9884]",
        "[-94.8682,39.0596]",
        "[-94.6053,39.0432]",
        "[-94.6108,38.846]",
        "[-94.6108,38.7365]",
        "[-94.9668,38.7365]",
        "[-95.0544,38.7365]",
        "[-95.0544,38.9829]"
      ]
    ]
  ]
}
```

This replaces the arrays in the `.coordinates[][]` array with JSON encoded strings representing the serialized arrays.  This would no longer be used for processing without first passing the serialized arrays through `fromjson` in `jq`. However, if the output is only for visualization, it may be a good enough solution.

Applying the serialization one level higher:

```bash
$ jq '.coordinates[] |= map(@json)' file
{
  "type": "MultiPolygon",
  "coordinates": [
    [
      "[[-94.9065,38.9884],[-94.8682,39.0596],[-94.6053,39.0432],[-94.6108,38.846],[-94.6108,38.7365],[-94.9668,38.7365],[-95.0544,38.7365],[-95.0544,38.9829]]"
    ]
  ]
}
```

---

There is a tool called [`jtc`](https://github.com/ldn-softdev/jtc), which is inspired by `jq`, and which provides the usual pretty-printing and compact output formats for JSON documents.  It also has a "semi-compact" format where it displays the inner-most object in a compact manner:

```bash
$ jtc -tc file
{
   "coordinates": [
      [
         [
            [ -94.9065, 38.9884 ],
            [ -94.8682, 39.0596 ],
            [ -94.6053, 39.0432 ],
            [ -94.6108, 38.846 ],
            [ -94.6108, 38.7365 ],
            [ -94.9668, 38.7365 ],
            [ -95.0544, 38.7365 ],
            [ -95.0544, 38.9829 ]
         ]
      ]
   ],
   "type": "MultiPolygon"
}
```

I'm not very familiar with `jtc` so I can't immediately say whether this output format is configurable (a quick glance at [the user guide](https://github.com/ldn-softdev/jtc/blob/master/User%20Guide.md) suggests that it's *not* configurable in exactly the way that you want).  Note also that `jtc` will sort your objects by the keys.

---

You may also be interested in [`jless`](https://jless.io) if your aim is to explore or view the data manually in a terminal.  It would show you your data like this by default:

```
▼ {type: "MultiPolygon", coordinates: […]}
    type: "MultiPolygon"
  ▽ coordinates: [[[[…], […], […], […], […], […], […], […]]]]
    ▽ [0]: [[[…], […], […], […], […], […], […], […]]]
      ▽ [0]: [[…], […], […], […], […], […], […], […]]
        ▽ [0]: [-94.9065, 38.9884]
            [0]: -94.9065
            [1]: 38.9884
        ▽ [1]: [-94.8682, 39.0596]
            [0]: -94.8682
            [1]: 39.0596
        ▽ [2]: [-94.6053, 39.0432]
            [0]: -94.6053
            [1]: 39.0432
        ▽ [3]: [-94.6108, 38.846]
            [0]: -94.6108
            [1]: 38.846
        ▽ [4]: [-94.6108, 38.7365]
            [0]: -94.6108
            [1]: 38.7365
        ▽ [5]: [-94.9668, 38.7365]
            [0]: -94.9668
            [1]: 38.7365
        ▽ [6]: [-95.0544, 38.7365]
            [0]: -95.0544
            [1]: 38.7365
        ▽ [7]: [-95.0544, 38.9829]
            [0]: -95.0544
            [1]: 38.9829
```

... where each section is easily collapsable using the arrow keys.